# Read and Write a file in hadoop in pseudo distributed mode

Tags: file, hadoop, operations

I want to open/create a file and write some data in it in hadoop environment. The distributed file system I am using is hdfs.
 I want to do it in pseudo distributed mode. Is there any way I can do this. Please give the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post fits to your problem :-)

[Writing data to hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533330/writing-data-to-hadoop/1629845#1629845)